# How can write XML with POCO library in ROS environment

Tags: c++, xml, ros, poco-libraries

I want to create C++ program which read and write xml using POCO library.

So, I write simple program.

I could read each xml elements.

But I could't write new xml elements.

Below is test.xml.

```
<config>
    <prop1>value1</prop1>
</config>
```

And this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Poco/AutoPtr.h>
#include <Poco/Util/XMLConfiguration.h>

using Poco::AutoPtr;
using Poco::Util::XMLConfiguration;

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    AutoPtr<XMLConfiguration> pConf(new XMLConfiguration("test.xml"));

    std::string prop1 = pConf->getString("prop1");
    std::cout << "prop1 =  " << prop1 << std::endl;

    pConf->setString("prop2", "input");
    pConf->save("test.xml");

    return 0;
}
```

After this program run, I want the xml file to change as below.

```
<config>
    <prop1>value1</prop1>
    <prop2>input</prop2> <--New element added!!
</config>
```

But result is as below.

```
<config>
    <prop1>value1</prop1>
</config>
```

Nothing changed...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Added information as below**

- OS :: Linux Mint18.1
- POCO library version :: 1.7.6 (Build from source code)
- Build system :: CMake and make and GCC

I run following command.

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

Then, I could write xml file using above program.

I think ros uses POCO library and It is duplicate my POCO library.

So I try to replace POCO library(ros) to POCO library(mine).

My attempt went well!

Comment: for me worked as expected. Which version of Poco you used?

Comment: Thanks for replay! I add new information.

Comment: example is work if you write into another file?

Comment: No, I got same result. But I get solution. ROS(robot-operation-system) gone wrong with my program. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Solution is as below**

If you can read xml files and can't write xml files using POCO library.

Your POCO library and ROS's POCO library may be duplicated.

Try following commands.

1. Install ROS

   sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
2. Reinstall Poco library with **destination prefix** to /usr/lib and /usr/include

   ./configure **--prefix=/usr**

   make

   sudo make install